# run kitchen pentaho batch windows script from another batch file example

Tags: windows, batch-file, pentaho, pdi, pentaho-ctools

I am having issues at running  the kitchen.bat file from another batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 

REM IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Transform.exe" 
SET Transform="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Transform.exe"
set tmpDate=%date%
set tmpTime=%time: =0%
set varDate=%tmpDate:~6,4%%tmpDate:~3,2%%tmpDate:~0,2%
set varTime=%tmpTime:~0,2%%tmpTime:~3,2%%tmpTime:~6,2%
set varDateLog=%tmpDate:~0,2%/%tmpDate:~3,2%/%tmpDate:~6,4%
set varTimeLog=%tmpTime:~0,2%:%tmpTime:~3,2%:%tmpTime:~6,2% 
set Traitement=%~n0%~x0
set "varKettleDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PENTAHO_data-integration";%varKettleDir%
set varDir=%HOMEDRIVE%\Temp\advans\bi\cm
set varLog=%varDir%\logBatch
set LOG=%varLog%\AdvansCam_%varDate%_%varTime%.log
set ADV_ETL_CLIENT=%HOMEDRIVE%\SVN\ADV_ETL_CLIENT_REP

REM %Transform% -s:"%~f1" -xsl:"%~dpn0.xsl" 2>NUL

REM ENDLOCAL
REM GOTO:EOF


REM :Syntax
REM 


echo %varDateLog% %tmpTime:~0,2%:%tmpTime:~3,2%:%tmpTime:~6,2% ^| ... Erreur : Le paramètre Date arreté n'est pas présent >> %LOG%
echo %varLog%\Advans_CamInit%~x0^| Debut du traitement >> %LOG%
echo ~x0=%~x0 >> %LOG%
echo ~x=%~n0%~x0 >> %LOG%
rem -- PENTAHO DATA INTEGRATION
REM set varPentaho= "%varKettleDir%\kitchen.bat /file:%ADV_ETL_CLIENT%\J_STG_push.kjb /level:Basic > %varLog%\JobCamClient_%varDate%_%varTime%.log"
REM call %varPentaho% && echo %varPentaho% "OK" || echo %varPentaho%"NOK" >> %LOG%
REM echo Debut du traitement >> %LOG%
cmd kitchen.bat /file:%ADV_ETL_CLIENT%\J_STG_push.kjb /level:Basic > %varLog%\JobCamClient_%varDate%_%varTime%.log" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK" >> %LOG%
```

Comment: and what are these problems?

Comment: i don't succeed to run the kitchen.bat

Comment: basically i am seeking advice on how to run the kitchen file from another batch file as shown in the above code

Answer (score 1):

try with this line:

```
call  kitchen.bat /file:%ADV_ETL_CLIENT%\J_STG_push.kjb /level:Basic > %varLog%\JobCamClient_%varDate%_%varTime%.log"  && (
  echo "OK">>%LOG%
) || (
  echo "NOK" >> %LOG%
)
```

instead of your last one.

Comment: okay would do it in morning here at the office 'morrow ........ thank you but just to inform you i have tried it previously but infortunately i had the NOK displayed on the log

Comment: please i need your help on this other question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138791/server-connection-through-a-batch-file-script